# Generating an email with powershell -comobject outlook.application add CC

Tags: powershell, email, outlook, cc

I have found several topics about similar issue but I can not find any documentation for this and none of those correspond my issue directly.

```
$ol = New-Object -comObject Outlook.Application
$newmail = $ol.CreateItem(0) 
$newmail.Recipients.Add($Manager.EmailAddress)
$newmail.Recipients.Add($User.EmailAddress)
```

The only thing I need is to make the 2nd receipient ($User.EmailAddress) in CC field instead "to" field in Outlook's draft. How can I accomplish it? Moreover is there any documentation about those functions?

Cheers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the default recipient type is `olTo`, you need to give the second recipient a different type, namely `olCC`:

```
$ol = New-Object -comObject Outlook.Application
$newmail = $ol.CreateItem(0) 
# the manager goes in the 'To'
$newmail.Recipients.Add($Manager.EmailAddress)

# this one should go in the 'CC'
$recip = $newmail.Recipients.Add($User.EmailAddress) 
$recip.Type = 2
```

for Outlook Recipient Type enum look here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/VBA/Outlook-VBA/articles/olmailrecipienttype-enumeration-outlook

Comment: Damn. Was trying the same but with $recip.Type = olCC. Thanks mate! Works like a charm!